# Changes to WordPress database using phpMyAdmin not reflected on blog

Tags: debug, cache, troubleshooting

I am updating my database using the phpMyAdmin UI and the changes are not reflected on the WordPress blog. The reason for doing this is when some changes were made recently to the blog the site hanged and was looking at reverting the code changes from the database side.

When updating a blog using the WordPress admin dashboard i am able to update it. But not able to update it from the back-end database. I have disabled the plugins and ensured that there is no caching . The only caching entry in the `wp-config.php` file is set as false .

```
define('WP_CACHE', false); //Added by WP-Cache Manager
```

Please guide who to add changes to the database and the same be reflected or reverted from a blog entry on WordPress.

Comment: Are you sure that you are updating the right database?

Comment: Yes as the entries entered from the wp_admin dashboard are having entries in the same table. But editing the backend table directly is not reflecting on the blog.

Comment: What data tables are you updating?

Comment: What part of the wordpress did you made changes to that led to this? did you make changes in wordpress core files? Or plugin files?

Comment: Thanks all for the help.Figured the problem out every time you make changes from the backend database wordpress stores that as a revision in the wp_post table with a post type entry along with a revision which is shown at the top. The original record is there down below and when that is edited it reflects back on the blog. The key to editing from the backend would be to get hold of the main record entry instead of the revision record.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the php error log to debug your issue. 
You can find the error log using this command in the terminal is you are using linux.

```
sudo su
cd /var/log/apache2/
sudo gedit error.log
```

Now if you debug properly you will get to know where the changes went wrong.